# Unable to access form data in webflux/webclient

Tags: spring-webflux

I am getting 400 bad request when I access form data through @RequestParam

My Java code

```
public Flux<String> postWithFormData() {

    MultiValueMap<String, String> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
    map.add("id", "Test Post Form data");

    return webClient
            .post()
            .uri("http://localhost:8080/webclient/rest6")
            .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
            //.syncBody(map)
            .body(BodyInserters.fromFormData("id", "Test Post Form data"))
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToFlux(String.class);

}
```

Controller class

```
@RequestMapping(value = "rest4", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<String> rest4(@RequestParam("id") String id) {
    ResponseEntity<String> response = new ResponseEntity<String>("Success",HttpStatus.OK);
    return response;
```

}

How to access form data in controller?

Answer (score 6):

You need to use ServerWebExchange.

```
@PostMapping(value = "webclient/rest6", consumes = {"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"})
public Mono<String> redirectComplete(ServerWebExchange exchange) {
    Mono<MultiValueMap<String, String>> data = exchange.getFormData();

    return data.map(formData -> {
        String parameterValue = formData.getFirst("id");
        ...
        return Mono.just("result data");
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your *postWithFormData()* code is OK.

The problem is in your *rest4(..)* method. You can't use *@RequestParam* annotation in order to get POST parameter (it should be used to get GET parameters).

You can use DTO instead. If you change the code this way it should work:

```
  @PostMapping(value = "rest4")
  public ResponseEntity<String> rest4(ValueDto value) {
    System.out.println(value.getId());
    ResponseEntity<String> response = new ResponseEntity<String>("Success", HttpStatus.OK);
    return response;
  }

  static class ValueDto {
    private String id;

    public String getId() {
      return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
      this.id = id;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks it is working. Can you help with Multipart file, what should be the class type that it binds to? If I put MultipartFile it is throwing exception

Comment: Do you mean endpoint or client? For endpoint i use such signature:
@PostMapping(value = "/upload", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
public Mono<ResponseEntity<RestResponse>> upload(@RequestPart("file") Mono<FilePart> monoFilePart) {..}